# How to read keys into array?

Tags: puppet

I am trying to read keys from a hiera json file into an array.

The json is as follows:

```
{
  "network::interfaces": {
    "eth0": {
      "ip": "10.111.22.10"
    },
    "eth1": {
      "ip": "10.111.22.11"
    },
    "eth2": {
      "ip": "10.111.22.12"
    }
  }
}
```

In my Puppet code, I am doing this:

```
$network_interfaces = hiera_array('network::interfaces')
notice($network_interfaces)
```

Which results in the following:

```
Notice: Scope(Class[Role::Vagrant]): {eth0 => {ip => 10.111.22.10}, eth2 => {ip => 10.111.22.11}, eth3 => {ip => 10.111.22.12}}
```

But what I want are just the interfaces:  [eth0, eth1, eth2]

Can someone let me know how to do this?

Comment: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/function.html#keys. Given that you are invoking `hiera_array`, I have to assume you are using an unsupported version of Puppet from 2+ years ago, so you will need the `stdlib` module for that function.

Comment: I am running version 4.8.2, so will use stdlib.  Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `hiera_array()` and plain `hiera()` has to do with what happens when the requested key (`network::interfaces` in your case) is present at multiple hierarchy levels.  It has very little to do with what form you want the data in, and *nothing* to do with selecting bits and pieces of data structures.  `hiera_array()` requests an "array-merge" lookup.  The more modern `lookup()` function refers to this as the "unique" merge strategy.

It seems unlikely that an array-merge lookup is in fact what you want.  In that case, the easiest thing to do is read the whole hash and extract the keys:

```
$network_interfaces = keys(hiera('network::interfaces'))
```

In Puppet 4 you'll need to use the `keys()` function provided by the puppetlabs/stdlib module.  From Puppet 5 on, that function appears in core Puppet.

Comment: I was able to get this done using keys().  Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: So is there a way to do this in Puppet 3?

Comment: @DavidC, you should be able to do it the same way in Puppet 3 that you can in Puppet 4.